# hypothesis testing on median using 100,000 simulations to estimate p-value

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, median

I'm trying to find out if the median time until failure (in hours) of some component after it’s been exposed to moisture is shorter than advertised.

The time until failure is believed to be Weibull distributed with shape parameter
$k = 0.25$ and $\lambda = 10$.

So I'm trying to test the following hypothesis:

$H_0$: median = 2.308

$H_A$: median < 2.308

Where there are 10 sample data provided with 7 of them being < 2.308.

So my sample stats is $S = 7$ where $S$~$Bin(n=10,p=0.5)$

I'm trying to simulate the p-value for the hypothesis test using R using 100,000 simulations to estimate the p-value. I'm not quite sure how to do this and any sort of guidance would be appreciated.

EDIT: the question is:  Describe the steps you would take to use R to simulate the p-value for the hypothesis test that you would use to test the company’s claim

Comment: @BruceET I'm trying to test whether or not the time until failure of some component after it's been exposed to moisture follows the Weibull distribution with the following parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $W \sim \mathsf{Weibull}(k=.25,\lambda=10),$ then the median of $W$ is $2.308,$ as you say.
In R:

```
qweibull(.5, .25, 10)
[1] 2.308351
```

However, I wonder whether you really want to use $S \sim \mathsf{Binom}(10, .5).$ That
seems to assume that the median of $n=10$ observations from 
$\mathsf{Weibull}(k=.25,\lambda=10)$ is also $2.308.$

Simulating 100,000 samples of size $n=10$ from $\mathsf{Weibull}(k=.25,\lambda=10),$
one finds that the medians of such samples fall below 2.308 with
probability about 0.45 (not 0.5).

Here are two equivalent simulations. The first simulates one sample of ten at a time over $10^5$ iterations and finds the sample median for each. The second puts all
100,000 samples of ten into a matrix of 100,000 rows and ten columns, and the
finds the sample median of each row.

[Answers are exactly the same for both simulations because I set the same seed for both
and used the simulated Weibull realizations in the same order for both. A second run of the first program with an unknown seed gave 0.45072. The 95% margin of simulation error is about $\pm 0.003,$ so with $m = 10^5$ iterations we can expect almost 2-place accuracy.]

```
set.seed(2020)
med.10 = replicate(10^5, median(rweibull(10,.25,10)))
mean(med.10 < 2.308)
[1] 0.45061

set.seed(2020)
m = 10^5;  n = 10
x = rweibull(m*n, .25, 10)
DTA = matrix(x, byrow=T, nrow=m)
h.10 = apply(DTA, 1, median)
mean(h.10 < 2.308)
[1] 0.45061
2*sd(med.10 < 2.308)/sqrt(10^5)
[1] 0.003146897
```

Finally, the probability of getting seven or more medians-of-ten below 2.308 out of ten samples is
about 0.10, which is the P-value you seek. This is computed from the distribution
$\mathsf{Binom}(10, 0.45).$  $[$If $S\sim \mathsf{Binom}(10, .45),$ then
$P(S \ge 7) \approx 0.10.]$

```
sum(dbinom(7:10, 10, .45))
[1] 0.1019949
```

I will leave it to you to do a simulation in a style appropriate to your class
and to fill in the gaps of the argument leading to the P-value.

*Note:* The distribution of the median of ten observations from $\mathsf{Weibull}(k=.25,\lambda=10)$ (histogram) is not the same as the parent distribution (density function in red).

[image]

Comment: would $0.45061$ be the p-value?

Comment: I think the P-value comes from the binomial computation for getting 7 or more samples with median below 2.308.

Comment: why are we finding mean(med.10 < 2.308)?

Comment: `med.10 < 1.308` is a logical vector with elements taking values `TRUE` or `FALSE`. The `mean` of a logical vector is its proportion of `TRUE`s.  So `mean(med.10 < 2.308)` approximates the probability that the median of 10 Weibull obs is less than 2.308.